# Laravel PHP foreach(User::all() as $user) performance

Tags: php, performance, laravel

if I write a foreach loop like this, is the method `all()` called every loop again or only once?

```
foreach(User::all() as $user) { ... }
```

In C# I know, the `all()` function is only executed once. But in php also?

Or is it faster if I hold the data in a variable like this?

```
$users = User::all();
foreach($users as $user) { ...}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both pieces of code will do the exactly same job and will create just one DB query, but I'd go with this for better readability:

```
$users = User::all();
foreach ($users as $user) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, then I use my first example, its cleaner and I need one row less in blade template ;)

Comment: @Phil795 DB or Eloquent code should not be in templates. Ideally, put it in the model. If it's a just a small app for fun, you can put it to the controller. Also, I'm pretty sure you will change this query to something different in the future, so I'd go with the second piece of code anyway.

Comment: It's only a simple user list, I think there is no reason to create a UserController only to display.
But of course, "bigger" pages are seperated in controllers

Comment: The other problem with this approach is that when you have 4000 users this page will fall over.

Comment: I understand your consider, but the application has a fixed size of 300 users.